# Pin variable used in extend assembly to any register than has a 1 byte extension register and use that extension register in the assembly

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

Basically I am wondering if I can use [explicit local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables) to pin a variable to either `rax`, `rbx`, `rcx` or `rdx` and then use the registers 1 byte extension in inline assembly.

I want to let the compiler decide which register would be best to use but it needs to be one of these and I need to be able to access its 1 byte extension register in the inline assembly.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit:
I need to stayoff the stackoverflow for a bit, getting a bit too lazy for my own good

Comment: I think you're asking if you can use a `uint64_t` input to an `asm` statement and then access the low-byte partial register of whatever register the compiler picks.

You don't need register-asm variables for that, and partial registers aren't called "extension registers".  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers - use `%b0` to get the low byte of whatever register the compiler picked for operand `0`.  In 64-bit mode, *every* register has a low-byte partial register, like `r8b` or `sil`.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use explicit local variables if you want to let the compiler choose. Just use a 8 bit variable and register and be done with it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Use the `q` constraint to have gcc pick a register for which the `b` modifier is valid.

Comment: @fuz: yup, that's good documentation, or good if you want to write it so the same asm statement could compile for 32-bit mode, where `q` isn't equivalent to `r`.